# How to show a view depending on the logged-in user's state?

Tags: jsf, view, seam, state

I currently have a server with an EJB which is called by a session scoped bean. The EJB essentially figures out which state the user has, i.e. which view the frontend should show. The user simply logs in and is redirected to the view in question. At the moment the EJB returns a POJO wherein a state enum is defined from where the session scoped bean finds out which view to show. My question is, is there a more elegant way of doing this? I'm new to JSF, Facelets and Seam, but have a lot of experience in MVC and MVP using listeners and observer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  <page view-id="/pagewithlink.xhtml">
    <navigation>
      <rule if="#{identity.isLoggedIn}">
        <redirect view-id="/first.xhtml"/>
      </rule>
      <rule if="#{!identity.isLoggedIn}">
        <redirect view-id="/other.xhtml"/>
      </rule>
    </navigation>
  </page>
```